# Double XT with XX1?

Tags: gears

Is it possible to run Shimano front chain rings(xt 36/26)with xx1 for the rest of the drive chain? 
Currently running xx1 with 30 upfront. Loving it although am concerned I will need smaller gearing for a 7 day stage race.Si I am contemplating going to a double ring in front.Will also try a 28 in front but fear will run out of gears on flat sections.

Is it possible to keep the rear set up 42/10 xx1 and add a double in front (xt ??)

Please help. I'm trying not to to change whole set up for financial reasons while i definitely don't want any issues during the event

Comment: Are you in NZ? If so ask the bike mechanics thread on Vorb, there's a couple of guys who know 11 speeds on there.

Answer (score 1):

> So obviously you'll need front shifter and derailleur that'll fit the cockpit, brand doesn't matter for the front.
>
> XT front rings need to be 11 speed! since they come in different thickness for different chains/speeds.
>
> 99% you need a new/longer chain. Going 30 to 36 will give that rear derailleur a nice pull.
>
> That being said it's a bit of a hit miss, some people find it works OK, some find they have to very careful due to the range extremes. Then again if you never cross-chain, you may not notice.